# OSB stuck threads on xmlbeans method

Tags: java, oracle, threadpool, osb

in our production OSB server, we frequently have stuck treads. The stack trace is always the same, and ends up with the Method: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.IdentifierImpl.compareTo(Object).

I attach full stack trace of the problematic code.  I am not a thread dumb guru but imho what is really strange is that this thread does not seems to wait for a lock acquisition over an object as no indication of lock is present. Moreover it does not seem to wait for the response of an external service. It is just frozen in the xmlbeans class. I read somewhere that due to code enhancement maybe the stack trace is not 100% accurate so maybe the tread waits in some other method???

```
Environment information:
JVM:Jrockit R28.0.0-679-130297-1.6.0_17-20100312-2122-windows-x86_64Microsoft 
Operating System: Windows "Longhorn" version 6.1 Service Pack 1 (Build 7601) (64-bit)
Heap size: 4,00 GB
```

I also have the incident output that is created by OSB in cases like that. I opened the mission control recording but it also indicated that org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.IdentifierImpl.compareTo method is a "hot" one taking the 66.67%.

Also when we have many stucks i notice Garbage collector to run much much more frequently and CPU usage increases to 100% all the time.

I do not except from someone to write a direct solution but any indication of how i could investigate this thing further would be great.

```
####<29-10-2013 13:35:48 CET> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <KS-MA-OSBTST07> <osb_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '25' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <3be3803d83405319:34eb3ef2:141fecc615d:-8000-000000000001028d> <1383050148480> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '24' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "688" seconds working on the request "weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@4a153639[
POST /Presentation_Services/Public/MyProxy HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 914

]", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
    Thread-124 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '24' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" <alive, suspended, priority=1, DAEMON> {
        org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.IdentifierImpl.compareTo(IdentifierImpl.java:78)
        weblogic.xml.query.runtime.sort.DocOrderSort.comparison(DocOrderSort.java:48)
        weblogic.xml.query.runtime.sort.GeneralSort$INBComparator.compare(GeneralSort.java:297)
        weblogic.xml.query.util.QSortAlgorithm.nrQuickSort3(QSortAlgorithm.java:24)
        weblogic.xml.query.util.QSortAlgorithm.sort(QSortAlgorithm.java:171)
        weblogic.xml.query.runtime.sort.GeneralSort.sortEverything(GeneralSort.java:325)
        weblogic.xml.query.runtime.sort.GeneralSort.externalSortEverything(GeneralSort.java:421)
        weblogic.xml.query.runtime.sort.GeneralSort.fetchNext(GeneralSort.java:568)
        weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.peekNext(GenericIterator.java:161)
        weblogic.xml.query.runtime.qname.InsertNamespaces.fetchNext(InsertNamespaces.java:148)
        weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.next(GenericIterator.java:102)
        weblogic.xml.query.runtime.core.ExecutionWrapper.fetchNext(ExecutionWrapper.java:80)
        weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.next(GenericIterator.java:102)
        org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.XqrlImpl$XqrlPathEngine.nextToken(XqrlImpl.java:131)
        org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.XqrlImpl$XqrlPathEngine.next(XqrlImpl.java:142)
        org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._toSelection(Cursor.java:924)
        org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._toNextSelection(Cursor.java:920)
        org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._hasNextSelection(Cursor.java:908)
        org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.hasNextSelection(Cursor.java:2642)
        org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.selectPath(XmlObjectBase.java:469)
        org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.selectPath(XmlObjectBase.java:460)
        com.bea.wli.sb.stages.expressions.xpath.XPathExprExecutor.executeXmlObject(XPathExprExecutor.java:121)
        com.bea.wli.sb.stages.expressions.xpath.XPathExprExecutor.executeXmlObject(XPathExprExecutor.java:110)
        stages.transform.runtime.ForEachRuntimeStep.processMessage(ForEachRuntimeStep.java:50)
        com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageMetadataImpl$WrapperRuntimeStep.processMessage(StageMetadataImpl.java:343)
        com.bea.wli.sb.stages.impl.SequenceRuntimeStep.processMessage(SequenceRuntimeStep.java:31)
        stages.transform.runtime.ForEachRuntimeStep.processMessage(ForEachRuntimeStep.java:50)
        com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageMetadataImpl$WrapperRuntimeStep.processMessage(StageMetadataImpl.java:343)
        com.bea.wli.sb.stages.impl.SequenceRuntimeStep.processMessage(SequenceRuntimeStep.java:31)
        stages.transform.runtime.ForEachRuntimeStep.processMessage(ForEachRuntimeStep.java:50)
        com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageMetadataImpl$WrapperRuntimeStep.processMessage(StageMetadataImpl.java:343)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.PipelineStage.processMessage(PipelineStage.java:84)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.PipelineContextImpl.execute(PipelineContextImpl.java:896)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.Pipeline.processMessage(Pipeline.java:140)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.PipelineContextImpl.execute(PipelineContextImpl.java:896)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.PipelineNode.doRequest(PipelineNode.java:51)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.Node.processMessage(Node.java:65)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.PipelineContextImpl.execute(PipelineContextImpl.java:896)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.Router.processMessage(Router.java:196)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.MessageProcessor.processRequest(MessageProcessor.java:39)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.RouterManager$1.run(RouterManager.java:593)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.RouterManager$1.run(RouterManager.java:591)
        weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:350)
        weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:143)
        com.bea.wli.sb.security.WLSSecurityContextService.runAs(WLSSecurityContextService.java:55)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.RouterManager.processMessage(RouterManager.java:572)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportManagerImpl.receiveMessage(TransportManagerImpl.java:252)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.local.LocalMessageContext$1.run(LocalMessageContext.java:179)
        weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:350)
        weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:143)
        weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:60)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.local.LocalMessageContext.send(LocalMessageContext.java:144)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.local.LocalTransportProvider.sendMessageAsync(LocalTransportProvider.java:318)
        sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor383.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:575)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.Util$1.invoke(Util.java:57)
        $Proxy122.sendMessageAsync(Unknown Source)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.LoadBalanceFailoverListener.sendMessageAsync(LoadBalanceFailoverListener.java:136)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.LoadBalanceFailoverListener.sendMessageToServiceAsync(LoadBalanceFailoverListener.java:570)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.LoadBalanceFailoverListener.sendMessageToService(LoadBalanceFailoverListener.java:537)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportManagerImpl.sendMessageToService(TransportManagerImpl.java:505)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportManagerImpl.sendMessageAsync(TransportManagerImpl.java:409)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.PipelineContextImpl.doDispatch(PipelineContextImpl.java:511)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.PipelineContextImpl.dispatch(PipelineContextImpl.java:489)
        stages.routing.runtime.RouteRuntimeStep.processMessage(RouteRuntimeStep.java:83)
        com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageMetadataImpl$WrapperRuntimeStep.processMessage(StageMetadataImpl.java:343)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.RouteNode.doRequest(RouteNode.java:106)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.Node.processMessage(Node.java:65)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.PipelineContextImpl.execute(PipelineContextImpl.java:896)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.Router.processMessage(Router.java:196)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.MessageProcessor.processRequest(MessageProcessor.java:39)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.RouterManager$1.run(RouterManager.java:593)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.RouterManager$1.run(RouterManager.java:591)
        weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:350)
        weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:143)
        com.bea.wli.sb.security.WLSSecurityContextService.runAs(WLSSecurityContextService.java:55)
        com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.RouterManager.processMessage(RouterManager.java:572)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportManagerImpl.receiveMessage(TransportManagerImpl.java:252)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.http.generic.RequestHelperBase$1.run(RequestHelperBase.java:154)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.http.generic.RequestHelperBase$1.run(RequestHelperBase.java:152)
        weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:350)
        weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:143)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.http.generic.RequestHelperBase.securedInvoke(RequestHelperBase.java:146)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.http.generic.RequestHelperBase.service(RequestHelperBase.java:72)
        com.bea.wli.sb.transports.http.wls.HttpTransportServlet.service(HttpTransportServlet.java:106)
        weblogic.servlet.FutureResponseServlet.service(FutureResponseServlet.java:24)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:815)
        weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:224)
        weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:108)
        weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:206)
        weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
        weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3656)
        weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
        weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:308)
        weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:117)
        weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2204)
        weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2126)
        weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1412)
        weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:198)
        weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:165)
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide us the code where this error is deriving from. That way we could analyze the code for errors.

Comment: There is no code. It is a OSB proxy service.

Comment: The problem has been solved. It was caused by an external service which responded with a massive payload in some cases, making the OSB to wait more than 10 minutes  to get the huge amount of data. After we fixed this no more stuck traces. Configuration of connection timeouts for business services is always a good idea.

Comment: @gazgas I would post that as an answer to your question.  If you can, include where you set that, and what an error with that set looks like.  It gives other people searching for "stuck threads + OSB" a possible answer for a problem I think we've all encountered at some point or another.